# Java POST - the request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect

Tags: java, rest, post, java-8

this is the first time I'm programming a rest service in java and I have a 400 issue, it says

> the request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect

I send the correct format in postman and I am not sure, if my mistake is at my code level or in postman

This is my model

```
public class Model {

private int id;
private String descripcion;
private double precio;

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getDescripcion() {
    return descripcion;
}

public void setDescripcion(String descripcion) {
    this.descripcion = descripcion;
}

public double getPrecio() {
    return precio;
}

public void setPrecio(double precio) {
    this.precio = precio;
}
}
```

This is my GenericResponse

```
@Path("generic")
public class GenericResource {

@Context
private UriInfo context;

public GenericResource() {
}

static final List<Model> lista = new ArrayList<>();

@GET
@Path("listar")
@Produces("application/json")
public List<Model> listarProductos(){
    return lista;
}

@POST
@Path("guardar")
@Produces("application/json")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public List<Model> guardar(Model m){
    lista.add(m);
    return lista;
}
}
```

An this is what put in postman and the response
[image]

Comment: I believe you do not want the square brackets around your JSON, you are not sending an array.

Comment: @ScaryWombat: That comment really is an answer

Comment: Can you post your input here as the image is not available.